# Error al comparar hash en node.js utilizando bcrypt

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un sistema de registro de usuarios que funciona bien, en cambio al comparar el hash de la base de datos con la introduciza en un campo html me arroja el siguiente error

> Error: data and hash arguments required

Estoy enviando 3 parametros justo como lo dice en la documentacion, que es la password en texto plano, el hash y un callback. Gracias de antemano

```
'use strict';

 const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  email: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
 password_hash: DataTypes.STRING,
 password: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
}, {});

 User.login = (email, password) => {
  return User.findOne({
     where: {
        email: email
    }
  }).then(user => {
      if(!user) return null
        return user.authenticatePassword(password).then(valid => valid ? user : null)
})
 }

 /* =============== */
 /* METODO PARA COMPARAR HASH */
 /* =============== */

 User.prototype.authenticatePassword = (password) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash, (err, valid) => {
      if(err) return rej(err)

      res(valid)
    })
   })
  }

 User.associate = function(models) {
  // associations can be defined here
 };
 User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
   return new Promise((res, rej) => {
     if(user.password) {
         bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            user.password_hash = hash
            res()
        })
    }
   })
   })
 return User;
 };
```

Comment: Quizá estas mandando valores undefined o null en alguno de los dos primeros argumentos.

Comment: @ElliotWilliamson Tienes razon, al imprimir password_hash es undefined, alguna idea de el por que?

Comment: Prueba a imprimir el password que quieres comparar antes de validar

Comment: @ElliotWilliamson Ese si se imprime, el que da undefined es el pass_hash

Comment: El valor de this que tienes en tu callback en la promesa, ese es el error, si mal no recuerdo cuando un método no esta definido en un objeto, el valor de this seria el del objeto global, para repararlo crea una variable en el metodo del prototype y asignale el this.password_hash ahi y luego en el metodo de la promesa accede a la variable que creaste en authenticatePassword, te servirá por el closure que se creará.

Comment: @ElliotWilliamson Me sale this.password is not defined

Comment: Si, me volvi a equivocar, cuando usas la notacion de flecha ninguna de las dos tiene su propio this entonces esta usando el objeto global en ambos lados (de esto ultimo no estoy seguro pero en si ninguna de las dos tiene un this asi como esta actualmente),
la funcion que defines en el prototype declarala con la sintaxis tradicional usando function.

Comment: @ElliotWilliamson Tan solo tenia que utilizar function y no las arrow functions, gracias. Agregala a una respuesta para que te den recompensa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar la sintaxis tradicional para declarar funciones usando `function`, la función de flecha que se agrega como callback al instanciar la promesa usara el valor this del contexto de ejecución sobre el cual esta declarada que en este caso es el método authenticatePassword

Acá ya tomaría a User como referencia

```
 User.prototype.authenticatePassword = function(password) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash, (err, valid) => {
      if(err) return rej(err)

      res(valid)
    })
   })
  }
```